# Finding a specific ordinal digit(from a user entered number)

Tags: c

So Im writing a code that asks the user to enter 2 numbers, for example n and c. N can be any number that is within this range (-1000000, 1000000). C represents the ordinal number(user entered also) that is equal or higher than 1 and less or equal as the number of digits in number n.

So after the program finds the ordinal digit(from left to right) it has to print that number and its square. Before I post the code I have to say that I am not allowed to use loops, arrays, strings, basically anything complex. Basically I can only use if/else if and the literal basics.

This is where I am right now.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> 

int main() {
      int n,c,d;
      int count=0;
          printf("Enter number: ");
          scanf("%d", &n);

      if (n < -1000000 || n > 1000000) {
         printf("Wrong entry!");
         return 1; 
       }
   count=(n==0)?1:log10(n)+1;

         printf("Choose the ordinal digit you want to find the square of: ");
         scanf("%d", &c);

      if (c <1 || c > count) {
         printf("Wrong digit!");
         return 1;
       }
         return 0;
      }
```

I managed to write the code that calculates the number of digits in n by using the log10() function, but Im not quite sure how to find the ordinal digit(from left to right in this case) and then write its square. Im thinking I can use the modulo operator perhaps ? But I havent used modulo before so Im not really sure how that would work.
Thanks in advance everyone, any help is appreciated.

Input/Output example:

Enter number: 2451

Choose the ordinal digit you want to find the square of: 2

The chosen ordinal digit is 4, its square is 16.

Answer (score 3):

Int division often lends a hand here - you could do something like:

```
d = (n / (int) pow(10, count - c)) % 10;
```

Since n and the result of the power function are both ints (we needed to cast the output of pow(), as it gives a double), the result will be the division of n by 10^c without remainder. The ones column of this integer will be the digit you're after, so we can obtain it afterwards by just using mod 10.

It's `count - c` not just `c` so that the ordinals count in descending orders of magnitude, rather than ascending.

Hope that helps!

Edit: This works because in C, division of one int by another always gives an int (and the result is always rounded towards 0, regardless of sign).

Comment: Using `pow()`, a floating-point function, in the middle of integer arithmetic, is not a good idea.  Having said that, there isn't a standard function to raise an integer type to an integer power.  It's not particularly hard to write one, but it has to be written (at least once).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Do you say that since it might introduce float arithmetic error, or because it's overkill, or for another reason? I imagined that since we're dealing in integer multiplication that float arithmetic error wouldn't occur, but I could be wrong...If there's another reason would be interested to learn it

Comment: It's the risk of arithmetic errors.  You'll probably be OK, but it depends on the quality of implementation of the `pow()` function and the range of exponents used, etc.  There are overflow risks with any integer version of `pow()` that are not present with floating-point, but the conversion from `double` back to `int` does have risks too.  Also, if you work with 64-bit integer types, even `double` can lose precise information before the integer calculations do.  A `double` has effectively 53 bits in the mantissa IIRC, so if the answer as an integer uses more bits than that, you get errors.

Comment: Interesting! I'll be more wary from now on. Thanks :)